# Is there a SQLite data dump for the latest release?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, data-dump

Also, since it could probably by done by Jeff, should Jeff provide the data dump in other formats - SQL Server, SQLite, and XML instead of just XML? I'm not sure how intensive it is, but it would probably make it easier for people looking to use or mine the dumps if it was in a multiple formats.

Comment: I'm wondering if that +1 is for a SQLite version of the data dump or Jeff providing the data dump in more formats when he releases it.

Comment: Apparently, someone dislikes my idea. :\ Meta is so confusing sometimes. Please comment on this...don't just be all voting please.

Comment: Why don't you make a simple script that converts XML to SQLite? Jeff might be a lot more open to the idea when there is a script ready to run.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264565/when-was-the-last-data-dump-upload-to-archive-org

Answer (score 4):

> I'm not sure how intensive it is

It would be three times as intensive.. The issue with the data-dump is the file-size - releasing the data in three formats (basically) triples the file-size, and spreads out seeds over three torrents..

I don't think it's worth the hassle, and I think a better solution would be to include a few scripts to convert the XML data into other formats, the concentrate the seeds on one torrent (the XML distribution)

Hm, it might be a good idea to start a cwiki'd question to collect a few Python or Ruby scripts to convert to SQLite/MySQL/Postgres, C# code to convert to MSSQL etc etc.. Then the data-dump readme could simply link to that..

**Edit:** We shall see if it's a good idea: [Scripts to convert data-dump to other formats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28221/scripts-to-convert-data-dump-to-other-formats)

Comment: Last suggestion implemented: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28218/scripts-to-convert-the-monthly-data-dump

Comment: Damnit, I just posted the exact same question - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28221/scripts-to-convert-data-dump-to-other-formats - although mine has guidelines and such! :P

Comment: One script could be adapted to work with multiple backends. Just saying ;)

Answer (score 2):

We are programmers, we have `XML` schemas for breakfast and have data dumps at night. We sometimes get indigested, but that's what scripting languages where made for:

- [Python script to import/create SQLite3 database from SO data dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28103/python-script-to-import-create-sqlite3-database-from-so-data-dump)
- [Importing the Data Dump into anything other than SQL Server?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13810/importing-data-dump-into-anything-other-than-sql-server)
- [How do I dumo the StackOverflow Database?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26557/how-do-i-dump-the-stack-overflow-database)
- [What is the fastest way to load up the data dummp into SQL Server?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3481/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-load-up-the-data-dump-into-sql-server)
- [Anatomy of a data dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/anatomy-of-a-data-dump/2678#2678) (useful for your reference)
- [Scripts to convert the data dump to other formats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28221/scripts-to-convert-data-dump-to-other-formats) and
- [Scripts to convert the monthly data dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28218/scripts-to-convert-the-monthly-data-dump)

Both of the last are currently "empty".